# Serve socket and public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

In Ruby it is quite easy to spin up a web server for a local folder:

```
ruby -run -e httpd ./public -p 9090
```

Trying to get a closer emulation of my production deployments I want an easy way to spin up a web server that not only serves a local folder, but forwards missing requests to a background service reachable through a socket file.

Is there any quick way to get that feature without implementing a custom server?

Comment: Try to use  docker - > https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-on-docker? Or u can use Virtual Machine.

Comment: Taking the time to learn Docker and/or setup a Virtual Machine might be an amazing alternative to a online bash command. Unfortunately I still was hopping for a oneliner

Comment: docker - u download docker for Rails, copy ur script in docker run, and then start script in docker run - 2 commands.